# "known root subtree copied to incorrectly-named new root path"

Tags: svn

What does this svn error message mean?

```
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
erors:

...

"known root subtree copied to incorrectly-named new root path"
```

The context is that I am try to merge changes from a trunk branch to a 'feature branch'.  The error affects only files newly added to trunk, not files modified in trunk.  The 'merge' operation completed successfully. The error appears when I try to commit the working-directory changes produced by the merge.  I can commit files modified by merge, but not files added by the merge.

I have successfully merged and committed previous changes to trunk to this branch.

I get the same error from AnkhSVN and Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the `pre-commit` hook on the repo is preventing you from doing this and preventing you from committing. This is not a standard SVN error message / standard SVN setup. See what the script is doing / ask the administrator about it. If not able to figure out, post the script contents here.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll follow up with the admin.